# Angularjs selectable highlighted rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have following table in ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in items">
   <span>{{item.name}}></span>
   <span>{{item.age}}></span>
</div>
```

what I want to do is 
 Each row with mouse over is highlighted and clickable to passing the item to further process.

Please let me know how i can achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To highlight on mouseover you could use the :hover CSS Selector
- To pass item to further process, you could use [ngclick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

CSS

```
.hoverme:hover
{
background-color:yellow;
}
.clicked
{
background-color:green;
}
```

JS

```
<div class="hoverme" ng-repeat ="item in items" ng-click="doSomething(item)" ng-class="{clicked:rowClicked==item}">
   <span>{{item.name}}></span>
   <span>{{item.age}}></span>
</div>
```

**Update**

Example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/THBLzP4oupyxdvOjXLCM?p=preview)

Comment: This works fine except that once I click the row color doesnt stay yellow. Please let me know how the background color stays same untill another row is clicked. Thanks

Comment: not sure why select.js needs to exist for this plunker example, but this is hands down the best solution for highlighting table rows. I've seen answers with 114 ups that were nothing compared to this. Thank you.